# How can I change Image on switch case in android?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-imageview

I am building an android application where an user enter the fix thing in an edit text filed and the value of the edit text is parse to second activity using singleton class.

Now I need is that when the text on second activity ice-cream then there is an ice-cream image that is available in my project I just need is that in image-View the image of ice-cream display.

Let take second case if user enter the value food then the image of food should display in Image-view.

I think This can do from if..if else..else case. If I am right Please help me.

I am new to android.

Here is the code -

```
ImageView Imgsport = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sportimageevent);
TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText(m.getTitle());
```

Let me be more clarify if title is ice-cream then set image-view to ice-cream image.

Comment: Sonam, you can do this with switch as well as if...elseif...else, you say what you want to do?

Comment: How can I implement switch case as you are saying can you please help me with code..

Comment: sonam, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
 String value=m.getTitle();
        if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("icecream")){
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icecream);
        }else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("food")){
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.food);
        }else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("desert")){
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.desert);
        }else{
            //default case, if above all conditions will become false then this will call
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65513/discussion-on-answer-by-pratt-how-can-i-change-image-on-switch-case-in-android).

Comment: @bluefeet Sorry sir, but I can not chat that is why here extended chat is occured.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of different values then you can consider using switch with a hasmap.
something like:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("icecream",ICECREAM);
map.put("food",FOOD);
.
.
String str = m.getTitle().toLowerCase();
```

then convert this string to integer code

```
switch(map.get(str))
{
   case ICECREAM: ...
   case FOOD: ...
   .
   .
}
```